# Sessions or any alternatives in webAPI

Tags: c#, asp.net, design-patterns, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2

I have a business logic which has lot of DB fetch operations and a bit complex business logic.
Data fetched is rarely changed within the session of user.

- Many Fetch opertaions(data fetched is rarely changed within the session of user).
- For each and every action on the form(button click/ value change in Textbox etc...) we need to run the business logic to check if it's valid change.

Currently we are using Asp.net Forms Application and these business logic is in InSessionScope(). 
Currently we are working on migrating to Restful API(WebAPI).

- Can we use sessions(InSessionScope()) in RESTFul?
- If not in sessions how to avoid more database calls and use the same object on subsequent calls and increase performance?

Comment: `REST` is stateless and by adding `Session` you are making it stateful and  defeating any purpose of having it.

Comment: You can use the `Session`. Give a look at this https://forums.asp.net/t/1780385.aspx

Comment: Do not use a Session (in-memory) because you will have issues if you have more than one web server. Get familiar with authorization tokens, request scope and see how you can fit your business logic into it. http://www.dotnetcurry.com/aspnet/1223/secure-aspnet-web-api-using-tokens-owin-angularjs

Comment: @AfnanAhmad U r correct, is there any mechanism to avoid DB calls in subsequent calls and increase performance.

Comment: I think you are looking for Caching mechanism, I think there are plenty of resources for that.

Answer (score 6):

Based on my personal experience NEVER use Session in a Rest Application as AspNET WebAPI are .. even if you can .. but instead use Tokens for Authorization and User Profilation (with AspNet Identity) and for performance (don't hit DB too many times)  i suggest to you some ways as i have done:

1 - `USE CACHE!`! (there are some great frameworks and lib for cache ..you can use different Layers of cache .. Query .. Response of webapi ..for example I'm use to cache the entire API response (Json) and auto invaildate it on POST / PUT / DELETE request) ..in .NET you can use this `https://github.com/filipw/Strathweb.CacheOutput`
You can also use `Redis` for caching (if you don't want to cache locally in the Server but to have a distribuited cache)

2 - Try to think in `NoSQL` way .. in our application we use a mix of DB .. SQL Server but also `MongoDB` (expecially for big amount of data ) for example we use SQL server to manage  AspNEt Identity but we use MongoDB to store our Product (we have about 6 milions of products) and it take about 1 sec for query (also with aggregation!!) ..

3 - Try to use `LocalStorage` on the `FrontEnd` if you can to store some information. .and then sync them when you need ..

Hope it can help you.. enjoy WebAPI ..enjoy REST!! (and leave webforms as soon as you can ...in my idea!!)

Answer (score 0):

You can use tokens implemented by you or JwtToken.

If you choose implement custom token on login method you must return a token to you app, next in any api call pass this token like a header or query string and decrypt in server to validate propose.